# Is there a functional programming idiom for filtering a list into trues and falses?

Tags: python, functional-programming, filter

Say you have some list `L` and you want to split it into two lists based on some boolean function `P`.  That is, you want one list of all the elements `l` where `P(l)` is true and another list where `P(l)` is false.

I can implement this in Python like so:

```
def multifilter(pred,seq):
    trues,falses = [],[]
    for x in seq:
        if pred(x):
            trues.append(x)
        else:
            falses.append(x)
    return trues,falses
```

My question: Is there a functional programming idiom that accomplishes this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From itertools examples:

```
from itertools import tee, filterfalse
def partition(pred, iterable):
    t1, t2 = tee(iterable)
    return filterfalse(pred, t1), filter(pred, t2)
```

Comment: this is probably the best way to do it in Python. works with generators too. only flaw is that it's not a one-liner =P. But you could do that with some abuse: `lambda pred, iterable: tuple(f(pred,t) for f,t in zip([filter,filterfalse],tee(iterable)))`. not that that's.. better in any way

Comment: I was just thinking that I hadn't used `itertools.tee` nearly enough recently... thanks!

Answer (score 2):

[Hoogle](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/) is a good tool for this. You can enter a function type and see all functions with that type. In this case we need as input: a list of `a`, and a function that takes an `a` and returns a boolean, and the output is a pair of lists of `a`. In Haskell syntax that's `(a -> Bool) -> [a] -> ([a], [a])`. From there we see the relevant function is [partition](http://haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.12.1/html/libraries/base-4.2.0.0/Data-List.html#v:partition). Implementation:

```
partition p xs == (filter p xs, filter (not . p) xs)
```

In Python:

```
partition = lambda p, xs: (filter(p, xs), filter(lambda f: not p(f), xs))
```

Or this is faster, but a bit uglier cause it's asymmetric:

```
partition = lambda p, xs: (filter(p, xs), [z for z in xs if not p(z)])
```

This does do twice the number of calculations you need, though, but I think you have to do that if you don't have mutation.

Comment: Note that the OP tagged their question Python, so they may or may not be looking for a solution in that language. Good general answer though.

Comment: @Amber: yep, good point. I realized that too so I added a Python translation.

Comment: Wow, I hadn't seen Hoogle before. That's awesome!

Answer (score 2):

```
trues = [x for x in seq if pred(x)]
falses = [x for x in seq if not pred(x)]
```

That's the height of functional-programming style, unless you want more function calls.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a reduce that generates a 2-element tuple result.

```
reduce(lambda x,y: (x[0]+[y],x[1]) if somefunc(y) else (x[0],x[1]+y), somelist, ([],[]))
```

Returns a 2-tuple; first portion is a list of elements that make `somefunc()` return True, second is the rest.

Comment: Aha, it took me a second to figure out what was going on, but I like it.

Comment: it's clever, but pretty inefficient - you're creating lots of small lists and doing lots of list concatenation

Answer (score 0):

Sure there is.  In fact, there's one found in Python already.  Look under [itertools](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html) for the groupby function.  However, you're going to have to sort the list by the function type first.  I'm fairly certain that this is not what you're after but it's a start.

Me, I've always implemented what you're asking for via `ifilter`:

```
def multifilter( pred, arg ):
    return ifilter( pred, arg ), ifilter(lambda x: !pred(x), arg )
```

Comment: Yeah, the `groupby` and `ifilter` ideas will both work, but they make me feel dirty for taking what should be a single-pass operation and making it more complex.

Comment: Technically, this will break if you try to pass a generator or other iterator in as `arg`, since generators/iterators are single-pass. You'd need to use `itertools.tee` to generate two sets of items from a single generator.

Comment: @Amber Yup, saw Alex B's answer.  If I were to modify my answer there's a chance my answer could be voted higher than his.  I don't want that.